# Looping through column fields in MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm building a food menu on a webpage.  This menu includes drink items like Wine and Beer.  Currently, they are categorized by Red or White and the type of wine (Pinot Grigio, Chardonnay, etc.).  I have entered these wine items into a MySQL database with the following columns/values:

id(int), name(varchar), type(varchar), price_bottle(decimal), price_glass(decimal), red(bool)

My Current code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Wines WHERE type = 'Pinot Grigio' "); 


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $name = $row['name'];
    $type = $row['type'];
    $price_bottle = $row['price_bottle'];
    $price_glass = $row['price_glass'];
  echo 
  "<div class='foodmenu-item'>
        <div class='foodmenu-text'>
          <h2>" . $type . "</h2>
          <p>" . $name . "</p>
        </div>
        <div class='foodmenu-price'>
            <p>$" . $price_bottle . " / " . $price_glass . "</p>
        </div>
    </div>";
}
```

Which is fine if I wanted to display each item out individually, but I want to Group by 'type' of wine (Pinot Grigio, Chardonnay, etc.) and then list each name of the wine under that 'type' so my CSS looks neat and organized.

For Example:

**PINOT GRIGIO**

*Nobllissimo*

*Riff*

**CHARDONNAY**

*The Crusher*

*Bogle*

Using the "GROUP BY" SQL syntax only displays the first result with my current code.  All my attempts at making a foreach statement result in error, I'm not sure where to turn next.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You need to use `order by`

Comment: First order results by the "type", then use a variable such as `current_type` and display the heading each time the type changes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tries using 2 queries nested? Like this:

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT(type) FROM Wines ORDER BY type"); 

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {

    $type = $row['type'];

  echo "<div class='foodmenu-item'>
        <h2>" . $type . "</h2>";

          $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Wines WHERE type = '".type."' ");

          while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
            $name = $row2['name'];
            $price_bottle = $row2['price_bottle'];
            $price_glass = $row2['price_glass'];
            echo "
                <div class='foodmenu-text'>
                <p>" . $name . "</p>
                </div>
                <div class='foodmenu-price'>
                    <p>$" . $price_bottle . " / " . $price_glass . "</p>
                </div>";
          }
  echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: For some reason this only returns "<div class='foodmenu-item'> <h2>" . $type . "</h2>"; </div>" for each type

Comment: This fixed it!  You were missing a "$" on the type variable and the "<div class='foodmenu-text'>" needed to be moved up above the <h2> tags but it works!  Thank you have a great day!

Comment: Wait what the heck?  I've changed nothing and it's broken again.

Comment: Ahhh figured it out.  It was just the missing "$" from the type variable in the result2 call.  Didnt need to move the "<div class='foodmenu-text'>" up, PERFECT! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

1. good manner is don't simply use "*", but list of columns
   (reason: select only data which realy want to use - better performance, second if you later want add or change columns in the table then your life will be simplier ;-) )
2. I think you can try, select all from small table and only sort the data - type and name, then in while cycle do it group about type for your menu. Then you need only one query send to database and have all of it. Assumption is Wines is only small table, because select all consume a memory.

   SELECT type, name, price_bottle, price_glass 
   FROM Wines 
   ORDER BY type, name;